# Getting MIMEMultipart/MIMEText to work with pyramid_mailer

Tags: html-email, pyramid, mime

I would like to send a formatted email with its plain text alternative :

```
body_plain = "content of the email with variables %(var1)s %(var2)s etc"
body_html = """"<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <body><p>content of the email with variables %(var1)s %(var2)s etc</p></body>
    </html>"""
vars = {'var1': var1, 'var2': var2}
```

With smtplib, I just had to pass the following msg:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["From"] = sender
msg["To"] = recipients[0]
msg.attach(MIMEText(body_plain % vars, 'plain')) # format 1 : text
msg.attach(MIMEText(body_html % vars, 'html')) # format 2 : html
```

to:

```
client.send_message(msg)
```

but what about pyramid_mailer ? I only succeeded in passing the plain body alone to the 'body' argument:

```
message = Message(subject=subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients, body=?)
mailer = get_mailer(request)
mailer.send_immediately(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found out there is no need for MIMEMultipart/MIMEText so far, since 'body' and 'html' arguments from pyramid_mailer.message's Message are enough

```
message = Message(subject=subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients, body=body_plaintext, html=body_html)
```